# Solving an integral equation with inverse Laplace transform

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function, gamma-distribution

Let $\alpha,\beta,\mu>0$.  I am looking for a solution, i.e. a function $g(x)$, that satisfies
$$
\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty g(x)x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}\,\mathrm dx=\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\mu\right)^{-1},
$$
where $\alpha/\beta>\mu$.  Note that such a solution would yield an unbiased estimator for $\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\mu\right)^{-1}$, i.e. if $X\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ then $\operatorname Eg(X)=\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\mu\right)^{-1}$. I tried solving this with an inverse Laplace transform by writing
$$
\mathcal L\left\{x^{\alpha-1}g(x)\right\}(\beta)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\beta^{\alpha}}\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\mu\right)^{-1}.
$$
I recovered $g(x)$ by taking the inverse transform of both sides and then multiplying by $x^{1-\alpha}$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
g(x)%
&=x^{1-\alpha}\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\Gamma(\alpha)s^{-\alpha}\left(\frac{\alpha}{s}-\mu\right)^{-1}\right\}(x)\\
&=-\frac{x^{1-\alpha}}{\mu}\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\Gamma(\alpha)s^{-\alpha}\left(1-\frac{\alpha/\mu}{s}\right)^{-1}\right\}(x).
\end{aligned}
$$
Using Bateman's Tables of Integral transforms, volume 1, $5.4.(9)$, this evaluates to
$$
g(x)%
=-\frac{1}{\mu}\Phi_2\left(1;\alpha;\frac{\alpha}{\mu}x\right),
$$
where
$$
\Phi_2(b_1,\dots,b_n;\gamma;z_1,\dots,z_n)=\sum_{m_1=0}^\infty \cdots\sum_{m_n=0}^\infty \frac{(b_1)_{m_1}\cdots (b_n)_{m_n}}{(\gamma)_{m_1+\cdots +m_n}m_1!\cdots m_n!}z_1^{m_1}\cdots z_n^{m_n}
$$
is the hypergeometric function of $n$ variables.  In this case we have a hypergeomatric function of a single variable; thus,
$$
g(x)%
=-\frac{1}{\mu}{_1}F_1\left(1;\alpha;\frac{\alpha}{\mu}x\right).
$$

> Unfortunately, this solution only yields sensible results if $\alpha/\beta<\mu$ (I have tried using some example parameters in MATLAB which demonstrates this). That said, what I am interested in is the case where $\alpha/\beta>\mu$. The formula in my table of integral transforms only has the restriction $\alpha>0$.  Maybe there is an error?  How can I get the solution to work for positive $\mu$?

We can check the solution which does seem to be correct.  Using G&R formula $7.522.9$ we find
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname Eg(X)%
&=-\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\mu\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}{_1}F_1\left(1;\alpha;\frac{\alpha}{\mu}x\right).\,\mathrm dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{\mu}{_2}F_1\left({1,\alpha\atop\alpha};\frac{\alpha}{\beta\mu}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{\mu}{_1}F_0\left({1\atop -};\frac{\alpha}{\beta\mu}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{\mu}\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{\beta\mu}\right)^{-1}\\
&=\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\mu\right)^{-1}.
\end{aligned}
$$
So I am puzzled as to why this solution does not work for $\alpha/\beta>\mu$.  One thing worth noticing is that when $\alpha/\beta<\mu$, the argument of the ${_1}F_0(1;-;\alpha/(\beta\mu))$ above is less than one and so the series defining it converges to $\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{\beta\mu}\right)^{-1}$ in the usual sense.  For $\alpha/\beta\geq\mu$ the aruguement is greater than or equal to unity and the series defining the ${_1}F_0$ diverges; thus analytic continutation is used.  Maybe this plays into the issue?  Here is a test in MATLAB showing disagreement when $\alpha/\beta<\mu$:

```
alpha = sym(10);
beta = alpha/8;
mu = sym(5);

syms x g(x)
g(x) = -hypergeom(1,alpha,alpha*x/mu)/mu;
for i = 1:512
    X = gamrnd(double(alpha),double(1/beta));
    est(i) = vpa(g(X));
end

mean(est) = -11979.51
(alpha/beta-mu)^(-1) = 1/3
```

Comment: Let $h_b(x) = g(x) e^{-b x}$ and $H_b(a) = \int_0^\infty x^{a-1} h_b(x)dx$ Then $H_b(a) = b^{-a} \Gamma(a) \frac{b}{a-bu}$ implies $h_b$ is equal to the Mellin convolution $h_b(x) = \int_0^\infty u_b(y) v_b(x/y)dy$ where $\int_0^\infty u_b(x)x^{a-1}dx = b^{-a} \Gamma(a)$ and $\int_0^\infty v_b(x)x^{a-1}dx = \frac{b}{a-bu}$ so $u_b(x) = e^{-bx}$ or $u_b(x)= e^{-bx} - \sum_{k \le K} \frac{(-b)^k}{k!} x^k $ and $v_b(x) = -b x^{-bu} 1_{x < 1}$ or $v_b(x) = b x^{-bu} 1_{x > 1}$, the "or" depending on the strip of convergence of those Mellin transforms.

Comment: I think some conditions might be missing here. For instance, $g(x) = (\alpha/\beta - \mu)^{-1}$ is a solution.

Comment: @Maxim you are right that that is a solution. That said, the goal is to come up with a function of the random variable that is an unbiased estimator of the r.h.s. I am not sure what other conditions could be specified other than the ones stated, I.e. a/b>u, a,b,u>0. Was there some conditions you had in mind that were omitted?

Comment: @Maxim I would also point out that the solution g(x) in my question works for u<0 but what I really need is one for when u is positive. I'm not sure how to adjust the approach to make that happen.

Comment: @reuns thanks for the suggestion. I am taking a look at this to verify and flesh out the details

Comment: There should be a closed form for $g$ which depends on $x, \beta, \mu$ but does not depend on $\alpha$. But I have no idea whether or not that would be useful.

Comment: @Maxim Why would the solution not depend on $\alpha$?

Comment: I'm saying that it's possible to construct such a solution, we have enough degrees of freedom for that.

Comment: @Maxim I see your point now.

Comment: @reuns Well I thought this was done until I realized that I need the solution in terms of $\alpha$, $x$, and $\mu$ as opposed to $\beta$, $x$, and $\mu$.  So I will need to use Laplace transforms.

Comment: At the very least, $g(x)$ cannot be positive for all positive $x$. If it is and the integral converges for $\beta < \alpha/\mu$, we'll have convergence for larger values of $\beta$ as well. But the equation says the integral diverges for $\beta = \alpha/\mu$. The inverse Laplace transform takes $\beta$ to the right of all singularities of $F(\beta)$.

Comment: @Maxim Yes you are right.  Taking the path of integration to the right of all the singularities, in particular the one at $\beta=\alpha/\mu$, seems to require $\beta>\alpha/\mu\implies\alpha/\beta<\mu$.  The question is what can be done about this to get a solution that works for $\alpha/\beta>\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that for my application the only useful result for $g(x)$ is one that does not contain $\beta$ and thus depends on $\alpha$, $x$, and $\mu$. 
 This forces me to use Laplace transforms to solve the problem.  I am posting this solution as a result of the comments from @reuns and @maxim which discuss using Mellin transforms. The equation numbers referenced to are from Bateman et. al. Tables of Integral Transforms.

To begin we have
$$
\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}g(x)\,\mathrm dx=\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\mu\right)^{-1}.
$$
In terms of the Mellin transform we write this integral equation as
$$
\mathcal M\{e^{-\beta x}g(x)\}(\alpha)=\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{-\alpha}\beta(\alpha-\beta\mu)^{-1}%
\implies%
g(x)=e^{\beta x}\mathcal M^{-1}\{h_1(\alpha)h_2(\alpha)\}(x),
$$
where $h_1(\alpha)=\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{-\alpha}$ and $h_2(\alpha)=\beta(\alpha-\beta\mu)^{-1}$. By $6.1.(14)$ we write the inverse transform as
$$
g(x)=e^{\beta x}\int_0^\infty t^{-1}\mathcal M^{-1}\{h_1(\alpha)\}(x/t)\mathcal M^{-1}\{h_2(\alpha)\}(t)\,\mathrm dt.
$$
By $6.3.(1)$ we find $\mathcal M^{-1}\{h_1(\alpha)\}(x)=e^{-\beta x}$. Furthermore, we want $\alpha/\beta>\mu$ so using $7.1.(3)$ we have $\mathcal M^{-1}\{h_2(\alpha)\}(x)=\beta x^{-\beta\mu}\mathbf 1_{(0,1)}(x)$. Substituting these results into the integral for $g(x)$ yields
$$
g(x)=\beta e^{\beta x}\int_0^\infty t^{-1}e^{-\beta x/t}t^{-\beta\mu}\mathbf 1_{(0,1)}(t)\,\mathrm dt%
=\beta e^{\beta x}\int_0^1 t^{-\beta\mu-1}e^{-\beta x/t}\,\mathrm dt.
$$
Let $u=\beta x/t\implies t=\beta x/u$, $\mathrm dt=-\beta x/u^2\,\mathrm du$, then
$$
g(x)=\beta (\beta x)^{-\beta\mu}e^{\beta x}\int_{\beta x}^\infty u^{\beta\mu-1}e^{-u}\,\mathrm du=\beta (\beta x)^{-\beta\mu}e^{\beta x}\Gamma(\beta\mu,\beta x).
$$
Finally, using DLMF $8.5.3$ we express this result as
$$
g(x) = \beta\, U(1,1+\beta\mu,\beta x),
$$
where $U(a,b,z)$ is the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind.

Here are some example parameters implemented in MATLAB:

```
mu = sym(1);
alpha = sym(10);
sigma = sym(sqrt(5));
beta = alpha/sigma^2;
syms x g(x)
g(x) = beta*kummerU(1,1+beta*mu,beta*x);
E = (alpha/beta-mu)^(-1);

for i = 1:512
    X = gamrnd(double(alpha),double(1/beta));
    est(i) = vpa(g(X));
end

vpa(E)
mean(est)
```

The results of the code show agreement with the derived result.  Thanks to @reuns and @maxim for their thoughts.